# Django updating an instance of a model based on user input from a dropdown menu

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, modelform

I have the following model in Django

```
class Medicine(models.Model):
    Medicine_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    User_Associated = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Tablets_In_Box = models.IntegerField()
    Dose_in_mg = models.IntegerField()
    Dose_Tablets = models.IntegerField()
    Number_Of_Boxes = models.IntegerField()
    Last_Collected = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Medicine_Name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tracker-home')
```

I am trying to create a form where a user can update the Number_Of_Boxes and Last_Collected fields of a given medicine which they are associated with. I want a dropdown menu where the user can select one of their medicines, and then update those two fields. I created the following modelform.

```
    class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        Medicine_Name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Medicine.objects.all())
       
        class Meta:
            model = Medicine
            fields = ['Medicine_Name', 'Number_Of_Boxes', 'Last_Collected']
    
        def __init__(self, user = None, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if user:
                self.fields['Medicine_Name'].queryset=Medicine.objects.filter(User_Associated=user)
```

I have the following view for this form.

```
def update(request, *args, **kwargs):
  
    instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CollectionForm(user=request.user, instance=instance, data=request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.User_Associated = request.user
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = CollectionForm() 
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'tracker/medicine_collection.html', context )
```

But I am running into problems with the primary key. The instance of the model which needs updating depends on the user input (i.e. the Medicine_Name) which they will choose from a dropdown menu. I don't understand how I can reference the instance, and where this needs to be done (since the primary key depends on what the user selects in the form).

Comment: You need to pass `id` in request in one way or another. Or other params which can be used as primary/alternative keys

Comment: Can you walk me through this/expand on what I need to do please?

Comment: If you show me how you serve objects in dropdown and how you send request from client side i sure will. But generally, when you fill your objects in templates, just add to elements `id="{{ object.id }}"` and then in request get this id with `$(object)[0].id` or `$(object).attr('id')` and pass it in `data` for server to use.

Comment: Well the dropdown menu is handled here (in my form) ` def __init__(self, user = None, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if user:
                self.fields['Medicine_Name'].queryset=Medicine.objects.filter(User_Associated=user) `